# How to get source code for Google Timer?

Tags: javascript

If you google "timer" you get a built in app/widget (what is it called?) at the top of the results. I would like to get just the source code for the timer and stopwatch in readable form for study purposes.

Comment: I don't get this widget here... (in Brazil?)

Comment: You cannot get the original source code for it unless google released it somewhere (unlikely).

Comment: Can't you always get source for javascript?